# TCP send queue getting stuck

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

In a scenario when there is a delay in network, even ACKs are getting delayed by about 32 mili seconds, TCP send buffer is getting full and its not clearing even after 5-10 min.

what can be issue here?
Is there any way that I can check current TCP send buffer status, so that I can stop outgoing traffic if buffer is getting full?
Any TCP config I should take care off?

Its happening in openldap2.4 stack.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will automatically stop sending if the send buffer is full: If the send buffer is full a send/write will either block (blocking socket) or fail (non-blocking socket). If you want to stop earlier just decrease the buffer with `setsockopt(..., SO_SNDBUF,...)`

Comment: And 32 ms delay is a really small value. How did you determine the issue is with the buffer?

Comment: You may try `ioctl(fd, SIOCOUTQ, &pending);` to get a snapshot of outgoing buffer load size (Linux only).

Comment: Steffen, Its a high traffic case where more than 2000 of req are being sent. 32 mili sec is RTT. one msg will be queue for around 32 mil sec causing the send buffer getting piled up. Even if I stops the incoming traffic send buffer is not getting cleared up. Will try ioctl(fd, SIOCOUTQ, &pending); if can get something there.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: It's not 'happening in OpenLDAP 2.4 stack'. It's happening in the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can check current TCP send buffer status, so that I can stop outgoing traffic if buffer is getting full?

It will automatically stop sending if the send buffer is full: If the send buffer is full a send/write will either block (blocking socket) or fail (non-blocking socket). If you want to stop earlier just decrease the buffer with `setsockopt(..., SO_SNDBUF,...)`
                    – Steffen Ullrich

Answer (score 0):

To check TCP send and receive queues on Linux, use the `ss` (sockstat) command [[man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ss)].

```
ss -tn
```

If you know the TCP port number you are interested in, you can filter for it for an easier view, for example:

```
ss -tn 'dport 389 || sport 389'
```

or

```
ss -tn 'dport ldap || sport ldap'
```